# CMS Pages display differently

Tags: cms, css, html, code

I just took over a site from another programmer and I am trying to figure out what he has done.  I have multiple CMS pages to include the home page.  The homepage displays correctly, but several of the other CMS pages seem to be missing some code that the home page has.  Why this would be, I have no idea, as each page has the same config, design, ect. set when I create the page.  What I have found is the home page has two additional  tags that the other pages that are not working d not have.  How can this be if they should all be pulling from the same template.  If you would like to see what I am talking about here are the pages.  The problem I am seeing starts after the footer-container  tag

Non working page - http://precisiondelta.com/backupold/index.php/contact/?___store=default

Working page - http://precisiondelta.com/backupold/index.php/

Hopefully someone can show me the way, so I can finish this job...

Thank you in advance,
Tommy

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you see as missing? I'm not seeing many template differences between the two pages. Which tags are you looking for in the footer-container div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main container div on the fawlty page has a float left. The footer on that page has a 'float:none;' This is why the footer acting weird I think.

Line 262 in local.css:

```
.cms-page-view .main-container {
float: left;
background: #000;
width:960px;
}
```

Also the homepage CMS page has an easy layout handle. Maybe there are some other modification done to that in a page.xml or local.xml file. Search for the layout handle name cms_index_index there.

Comment: Ok thank you for that advice.  It fixed that page, bu this one is doing the same thing and it did not fix that one.  Why would it work for one and not the other? http://precisiondelta.com/backupold/index.php/company-history/?___store=default

Comment: Heej, samen thing as before. the main container on this page has also float:left; The css in the local.css around line 274 targets several CMS pages: .cms-whats-new .main-container, .cms-company-history .main-container, .contacts-index-index .main-container. The main-container of all these pages get float left.